# How can i check if a value exists in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a status webpage in rails and i have a slight problem.

I want to check if an array includes a 'status: false'. And if this is true then an danger alarm comes up.

I allready have a solution, but i know it should go with a more "slim" code.
This is what allready works:

```rb
checkresults.map { |c| c.status }.include?(false)
=> true
```

this is the input of checkresults

```rb
checkresults = [Checkresult.new(status: false), Checkresult.new(status: true)
```

what i tried was

```rb
checkresults.include?(status: false)
```

the output i wanted was "true" but for some reason i get "false".

How can it work with just using one method for an array?

Comment: `checkresults.include?(status: false)`

returns false because theres' no `{ status: false }` in `checkresults`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `any?`:

```
checkresults.any? { |r| !r.status }
```

This will return a `true` or `false` for you.

Comment: I think `checkresults.any? { |r| r.status == false }` is much preferable, because 1) `any?` with `!r.status` requires more mental gymnastics; 2) it may not be clear to the uninformed reader whether you want to know if there are any `truthy` values or any `falsy` values; and 3) the reader may wonder what role, if any, might be played by `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
checkresults.map(&:status).include?(false)
```

Which doesn't change anything about your current code except the notation used. However this is not the fastest solution. Since you'll have to iterate the whole array, mapping the current element to its status. Followed by checking if the value `false` is included in the array.

Answers using `all?`, `any?` or `none?` are short circuited and stop iterating as soon as the condition fails (in case of `all?` or `none?`) or as soon as the condition is met (in case of `any?`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) or [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

```rb
# sample: any?
[true, true].any? { |flag| flag == false } #=> false
[true, false].any? { |flag| flag == false } #=> true

# sample: all?
[true, true].all? { |flag| flag == true } #=> true
[true, false].all? { |flag| flag == true } #=> false
```

You can use either of them

```rb
check_results.any? { |flag| flag == false }
!check_results.all? { |flag| flag == false }
```

Let's test

```rb
class CheckResult
  attr_reader :status

  def initialize(status: flag)
    @status = status
  end
end

# expect_true
check_results = [CheckResult.new(status: false), CheckResult.new(status: true)]
check_results.any? { |result| result.status == false } #=> true 
!check_results.all? { |result| result.status == true } #=> true

# expect_false
check_results = [CheckResult.new(status: true), CheckResult.new(status: true)]
check_results.any? { |result| result.status == false } #=> false
!check_results.all? { |result| result.status == true } #=> false

# shorthands
check_results = [CheckResult.new(status: false), CheckResult.new(status: true)]
!check_results.all? { |result| result.status == true } #=> true
!check_results.all?(&:status) #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of checkresults objects respond to `status`:

```
!checkresults.all?(&:status)
```

Comment: This doesn't prove there are some with value `false` ... It just proves there are none with value `true`. An empty array would return `true` in this case, which is wrong.

Comment: sory i didnt understand correcly, little fix will help)

Comment: Again, this is wrong as it requires `all` elements to be `true`, it isn't checking for `false` elements.

Comment: OP wants to check, if there is any `false` element. Its easier to check if there are all `true` elements in my opinion.

Comment: But it'll return `true` if they're all true. Rather than `false` which is what he wants. It needs to return `true` if there are any `false` statuses.

Comment: Ok) Adding `!` will fit all his needs. Don't you agree?

Comment: No. It's confusing code and doesn't convey the spirit of what they're looking to achieve.

Comment: Changing it to `!checkresults.all?(&:status)` does produce the correct result. @Jon calling it confusing is a personal thing, if you would translate it to text it says "not all statuses are truthy", which is quite understandable imo.

Comment: The only issue can be if there can be checkresults with `status: nil`, but I don't think its the point of this question. This construction doesn't confuse me at all if I read ruby code)

Answer (score 0):

Incase if want to check one **more** attribute columns You can use Pluck.

Use [#pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) as a shortcut to select one or more attributes without loading a bunch of records just to grab the attributes you want.

```
CheckResult.pluck(:status1, status2).include?(false)
```

checked both columns to will return a true or false.